# OpenFire disconnects very randomly with following error (XmppReceiverImpl.java initialize:134) - Error Occured Initializing the Receiver

Tags: xmpp, openfire, strophe

My OpenFire server frequenctly disconnectly in a random way with the below exception. I have written a strophe client to receive the notification from the xmpp server. And openFire runs with the apache CAMEL.

ERROR 2013-05-28 19:26:40,628 [http-bio-8181-exec-16] (XmppReceiverImpl.java ini
tialize:134) - Error Occured Initializing the Receiver
No response from server.:
        at org.jivesoftware.smackx.muc.MultiUserChat.join(MultiUserChat.java:498
)
        at org.jivesoftware.smackx.muc.MultiUserChat.join(MultiUserChat.java:392
)

And my openFire debug gives me following message in red color :
2013.05.28 19:26:24 org.apache.mina.filter.executor.ExecutorFilter - Exiting since queue is empty for /161.85.29.155:50429 
2013.05.28 19:26:24 org.jivesoftware.openfire.http.HttpSession - consumeResponse: org.jivesoftware.openfire.http.HttpConnection@125e5eb 
2013.05.28 19:26:24 org.jivesoftware.openfire.http.HttpSession - consumeResponse: org.jivesoftware.openfire.http.HttpConnection@14c009f 
2013.05.28 19:26:24 org.jivesoftware.openfire.http.HttpSession - consumeResponse: org.jivesoftware.openfire.http.HttpConnection@125e5eb

Any help on this regard would be useful.

Lokesh